# MUL operation in assembly

Tags: assembly, x86

i have the following assembly lines:

```
...
MOV ECX, 0x36EE80
MOV EDX, 0x95217CB1
MUL EDX
SHR EDX, 0x15
MOV DWORD PTR SS:[EBP-0x3C8], EDX
....
....
```

So, in http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/X86_Assembly/Arithmetic I have read that the value of the operand of MUL (in that case EDX) is multiplied with the value in EAX. So, in EAX I have the value 0330FD3B (decimal: 53542203). In EDX, i have the value 95217CB1 (in decimal: 2501999793).
But after the MUL operation i have in EDX the value 01DBEE41(in decimal: 31190593). But this must be wrong because 53542203 * 2501999793 is not 31190593...

Can someone explain me this ?

Comment: If this is specifically about x86 assembly, you should tag it as such.

Comment: When you multiply EDX by EAX, the result is in `EDX:EAX`. `0330FD3B` * `95217CB1` is `1DBEE41EB22A9CB` so `EDX` would be `1DBEE41` and EAX would be `EB22A9CB` forming the entire answer.

Comment: Read the link you posted more carefully, OP :)

Comment: Looks like this might be division by a constant, given how it's right shifting the high half of the result.  [Why does GCC use multiplication by a strange number in implementing integer division?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/41183935)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The description](http://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/processors/architectures-software-developer-manuals.html) for `MUL r/m32` is `Unsigned multiply (EDX:EAX <- EAX * r/m32).`.

That means that the *64-bit* product will be stored in `EDX:EAX`, i.e. the upper 32 bits ends up in `EDX` and the lower 32 bits in `EAX`. Which fits with the results you're seeing, since the product should be 0x1DBEE41EB22A9CB.

Answer (score 5):

Result is `01DBEE41 EB22A9CB`, EDX stores high part of it.
Decimal numbers are not concatenatable when dealing with binary representation of numbers.